# Find the list of Google Container Registry public images

Tags: image, list, public, google-container-registry

Where can I find the list of GCR public images?
In case of docker images, we can list it in hub.docker.com. 
But I couldn't find anything like that for GCR.

Comment: Please see my new answer. It's now possible.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

tl;dr There is no such thing, at least today.

GCR is first and foremost a private registry.  However, we respect the ACL's that users put on the GCS bucket backing their repository.  This is how we offer anonymous read to buckets like:

```
gcr.io/google-containers/...
gcr.io/google-appengine/...
```

Given a specific project, you can search within it using:

```
docker search gcr.io/google-containers/<substring>
```

Comment: What about for the subset of inside: `http://gcr.io/google-containers/` or `http://gcr.io/google-appengine/` ?

Answer (score 102):

The link to the list of Google Container Registry public images is: https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/google-containers/GLOBAL.

Comment: As it was clearly stated in the answer, there was no such thing when the question was asked. Google didn't had direct support for container registry in the console as they have now. Anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. The docker search didn't show any tags which I needed. It's ridiculously impossible to find this link -- many thanks for providing.

Comment: https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/distroless/GLOBAL for `distroless`

Comment: Is there a list of maintained projects like `distroless`, `google-containers`, `google-appengine`, etc.?

Comment: Note that `google-containers` was mostly used to host images related to the kubernetes project. This has now moved to `k8s-artifacts-prod`. So, the new version of the above link is: https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/k8s-artifacts-prod

Answer (score 13):

I think there's a different answer to this question now:

You can run:

```
$ gcloud container images list --project google-containers

NAME
gcr.io/google-containers/addon-resizer
gcr.io/google-containers/aggregator
gcr.io/google-containers/alpine-iptables-amd64
gcr.io/google-containers/alpine-iptables-arm
gcr.io/google-containers/alpine-iptables-arm64
gcr.io/google-containers/alpine-with-bash
gcr.io/google-containers/apparmor-loader
gcr.io/google-containers/busybox
gcr.io/google-containers/cadvisor
...
```

You can also directly use gsutil to list all the blobs in a public GCR bucket with:

```
gsutil list gs://artifacts.PROJECT_ID.appspot.com/containers/repositories
```

Answer (score 4):

For k8s.gcr.io and gcr.io

```
# k8s.gcr.io
# Access by browser or curl
https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/${namespace}/${image}/tags/list
# e.g. https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/sig-storage/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner/tags/list

# Access by browser,This is WebUI
https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/k8s-artifacts-prod/us/${namespace}/${image}
# e.g. web ui https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/k8s-artifacts-prod/us/sig-storage/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner

# gcr.io
# Access by browser or curl
https://gcr.io/v2/${namespace}/${image}/tags/list
# e.g. https://gcr.io/v2/gloo-mesh/cert-agent/tags/list 

# Access by browser,This is WebUI
https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/${namespace}/global/${image}
# e.g. web ui https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/etcd-development/global/etcd
```

ref [Document webui access to k8s.gcr.io](https://github.com/kubernetes/k8s.io/issues/1371) and https://github.com/anjia0532/gcr.io_mirror/blob/master/README.md#k8sgcrio-%E5%92%8C-gcrio-%E9%95%9C%E5%83%8Ftags

Answer (score 1):

"Distroless" images are also in public:

- Full list of distroless images on GCR: https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/distroless
- Distroless repo on GitHub: https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless