# Where does Kubernetes pull images and how can I browse them/change their pull source?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, container-registry

Where does a file like [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/nginx-0.20.0/deploy/default-backend.yaml) pull images like `image: k8s.gcr.io/defaultbackend-amd64:1.5` and where can I brows them?

The next release of `ingres-nginx` uses 1.15.6 which fixes CVE-2018-16843 and CVE-2018-16844. I want to see if there is an image from the source that `k8s.gcr.io/defaultbackend-amd64:1.5` is pulled from that contains images with that Nginx version.

I couldn't find the answer from the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/). I am not familiar with the default repos for Kubernetes. How would I configure a yaml file to pull from a specific registry with a URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

k8s.gcr.io is a registry service running on Google Cloud running as a service. In order to list the publicly available images or to find details about these images, please see one of the answers to an [older and similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35153902/find-the-list-of-google-container-registry-public-images).

> The link is https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/google-containers/GLOBAL. I'm not sure why it's so difficult to find.

In order to pull an image from a specific repository, just follow this semantics in your manifests:

```
image: <your-registry>/<your-project-path>/<your-container>:<your-tag>
```

e.g.:

```
image: www.myk8srepo.com/testing/nginx/defaultbackend-amd64:1.5.6
```