# who maintains the images found in https://gcr.io/google_containers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry

who maintains the images found in https://gcr.io/google_containers? is it Google? the only thing I've found regarding this public registry is just that, that it's a public registry. Who's pushing images to this registry? can they be trusted? I've seen some tutorials asking you to pull images from here.

Comment: I could not find an official reference. Whoever pushes to the Google repository must be authorized by Google. To list the Google maintained/authorized containers, refer to Ahmet's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44298851/8016720 Credit goes to @danyL for providing links in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are [maintained by Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35153902/find-the-list-of-google-container-registry-public-images).

In official [doc](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/overview#registry_names_as_urls).