# GCP Artifact Registry public google-container images

Tags: google-container-registry, google-artifact-registry

Since Google is pushing more on Artifact Registry and already announced that Container Registry is not actively developed anymore, is there a replacement for the public Google Container images, that are currently offered at https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/google-containers/GLOBAL ?

Comment: I did find this one, but those are examples: https://console.cloud.google.com/artifacts/docker/google-samples/us/containers

Answer (score 0):

This is the setup I'm using:

```bash
gcloud --project $PROJECT_ID \
artifacts repositories add-iam-policy-binding $REPOSITORY \
--location=$LOCATION --member=allUsers --role roles/artifactregistry.reader
```

In my specific case `PROJECT_ID=ansybl`, `REPOSITORY=public` and `LOCATION=us`.
Images can later be downloaded without being authenticated, e.g.

```bash
docker pull us-docker.pkg.dev/ansybl/public/canto
```

Comment: Are the images in the `ansybl` project managed by Google themselves? Because the `GLOBAL` images on Container Registry are.

Comment: Oh my bad, no it's not managed by Google, I indeed missed the point, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score -1):

Artifact Registry is the evolution of Google Container Registry which basically extends the capabilities of Container Registry. It comes with certain added features over Container Registry like **additional Artifact formats**, **support for both regional and multiregional registry host**, **support for repository-level permissions**, **Artifact Registry IAM roles**, **Google Kubernetes Engine image streaming** etc.

However, there is also an option for backwards compatibility and co-existence i.e., you can **use both Artifact Registry and Container Registry in the same project**. You can explore more on this from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/transition/transition-from-gcr?authuser=0).

Though, Container Registry is still available and supported as a Google Enterprise API, new features will only be available in Artifact Registry and is **highly recommended**. Container Registry will only receive critical security fixes.
You may also refer to a similar [Stackoverflow case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35153902/find-the-list-of-google-container-registry-public-images).

However, there are other alternatives to Google Container Registry for users who want to try different solutions.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. The question is whether Google themselves will migrate their public container images to Artifact registry. I already know what Artifact Registry is, which your answer explains.

Comment: I don't think Google support this, I can't find any public issue tracker regarding same.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone still looking for answer to this one, Google has official documentation on how to do this via IAM policies

https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/access-control#public

Comment: This does not answer the question. My question was regarding the public images that Google maintains, whether there's a replacement for those on Google Artifact Registry, instead of on Google Container Registry.